# "Send Mail As" is not receiving mail

Tags: gmail, alias

I'm struggling to set up a Gmail account to [“send as and receive as” a different email](https://www.howtogeek.com/142558/how-to-send-emails-from-different-addresses-in-gmail/). Right now, I can “send mail as,” but for no apparent reason, the email refuses to receive anything sent to it.

Details:

- This is a separate non-Gmail account (it's a cPanel/Dovecot account), and it's not set up via G Suite.
- I know for a fact that emails are making it to the first email account because I'm logged in via Thunderbird (which was the only way to confirm access anyhow).
- The server is in the form `secureXXX.servconfig.com`.
- I was able to get [“Check email from another account”](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/gmail-guide/lesson9/) to work, but this is not completely what I want, as it's very delayed (this is what I have as of now).
- I've also checked the spam and trash folders.
- Outgoing says: "Secured connection on port 587 using TLS"; Gmail offers no Incoming settings.

Am I forgetting something? Using the wrong ports? etc.

And are there no 'Incoming Server' options for Gmail's 'send as' configuration?

Answer (score 1):

So, this is not the correct answer, but the ["Check email from another account"](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/gmail-guide/lesson9/) seems to be a workaround for now.

And, to make it similar to the "send mail as" importer, I've chosen to check the first two options:

- Leave a copy of retrieved message on the server.
- Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail.

[image]